# Automapper Dependencies not resolved in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper, automapper-6

[image]

I want to add reference in my project Automapper as i am migrating from EF6 to Ef Core. So i need to add automapper which i had used. When i try to add from package console it get successfully installed but actually it is not as i can see at the right pane yellow color.

Can you please assist me, is there any other dependencies i have to add in json file ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your project.json file framework section like this

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"//This will missing in your json file
      ]
    }
  },
```